# Positioning figure over image issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

Hi guys im trying to do this on css but i cant  (im not css expert)
i have a span with a circle and number positioned over an image, on fullscreen works fine looks like this

[image: not mobile fullscreen]

But on mobile device is disconfigured

[image: javascript]

is there anyway to keep the circles fixed in any resolution??  the code im used to generate is this

```
    <script>
    
    var url = "https://parcelasfrutillar.cl/sug/admin/ci/index.php/admin/ajaxCall";
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            myFunction(myArr);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    
    function myFunction(arr) {
        var out = "";
        var i;
        
        for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                var num = arr[i].numParcels,estado = arr[i].estado, url_pan = arr[i].iframe_panoramico;
                var htmlstr = '';
                var div = document.getElementById( 'buttondiv1' );
                
                if(estado == 0){
                    if(num <=2){
                        htmlstr = '<a href="'+url_pan+'" > <span id="botoncss'+num+'" class="step1">'+num+'</span></a>';                    
                        div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', htmlstr );
                        
                    }
                }
            }
       
    }
    </script>


<style>
.planocl{
   max-width: 100%; 
display: block; 
height: auto;
}

.step1 {
    background: green;
    border-radius: 0.8em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 2vw;
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 2vw;
    font-size: 1vw;
}

    

#botoncss1 {
    top: 82.44%;
    left: 78.4%;
position: absolute;
}


#botoncss2 {
    top: 77.24%;
    left: 75.3%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Try using vh and vw instead of %

Comment: You cannot use any absolute units for this, nor units set by window size as aspect ratios can be anything. the positioning has to be done in relation to to the image. Please show us your HTML.

Comment: thanks man i put a div container in relative position and the span inside the div as absolute and works

Answer (score 1):

Use media query to adjust the position of `.step1` class according to screen width or height.

```
/* the css code above */
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .step1 {
    margin-right: 10px; /* ... I'm assuming you write multiple positioning attributes */
  }
}
```

If media query doesn't solve the issue, can you provide the link where you deployed your app?